# Illustrator - my rectangles are all sheared skewed?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I try to create a rectangle in a certain .ai file they all come out sheared:

[image]

but this isn't the case in other projects.  Is there any way to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost 100% sure your question is a duplicate.
 Anyway, check the prefs -

[image]

---

Otherwise disable the **Perspective tool** by clicking on its "x" in the Left-top corner.

Comment: my constrain angle is 0 degrees.  Different documents (tabs) seem to work just fine it's just this project :(

Comment: @Veta check these prefs while the file is open, plz

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/DlVPtmh.png might something else be causing this?

Comment: @veta disable Perspective tool - click on x of the tool on the upper-left corner and create a new rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

If you hold shift and press keys 1, 2 or 3 while drawing a shape it will shift the anchor points of your curser and will make the shapes appear sheared as you place them. Holding shift and pressing the 4 key while drawing the shape will revert it... Or it should anyway

Answer (score 0):

I moved everything to a new document and this resolved the issue.  Still super mysterious.  I am planning to buy some garlic in case it was ghosts.

Comment: this sentence is better as comment, not as an answer.... since we solved the issue.